# Could have benefits of one arm dumbell bench-press?

Tags: dumbbells, bench-press

I have incorporated dumbell bench-presses into my workout routine. I use progressive overloading, so every second or third workout I increase the weight I lift. Until now it has worked well and I have progressed well enough, but now I have run out of new weight plates to add (I do it at home, because I do not have gym access right now and I have restricted amout of plates obviously). So my first idea was to place plates from one dumbell to the other and I would do the bench-press with one arm at a time. So one set would consists of a same amount of reps with left and then right arm. But I do not know if is there any contraindication and will have this kind of excercise such benefits as normal dumbell bench-press has? Thy for your kind help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my favourite authors, Dan John, talks about the one arm bench press in his Easy Strength program, and how it should be a staple movement for horizontal pushing strength, as well as promoting symmetry across the body (if you can do 60kg for 5 on your right hand side, but only 30kg for 2 on your left, you may be a little asymmetric).

The only contraindication that I can see is you might get a few funny looks if you perform it in a commercial gym as it's not a particularly well known exercise. That and the possibility of a stronger core from having to stabalise the uneven load (hint: leave your unloaded hand free, don't be tempted to grab onto anything to help).

Basically, it's a great exercise, go for it!

https://www.t-nation.com/training/tip-bench-press-with-one-arm

https://www.t-nation.com/training/one-dumbbell-workout

Comment: I am very garteful for this detailed answer. Thank You Dark Hippo. I am sure I will incorporate this excercise into my routin soon. Thy!

Comment: @mahtantiwele No problem, glad I could help